# How to structure two eclipse workspaces and local and remote git repos

Tags: eclipse, git, joomla, egit

I have been using Eclipse IDE with egit and pdt for a couple of years. I have a local git repo outside my workspace and a remote private repo, largely for bckup - I am the only active developer. In addition to my projects (several sub-projects) I have imported a Joomla installation so that I can debug my projects in their working environment. So far so good.

Recently, I needed to start work on a big upgrade. So I created a new workspace and a new local git repo cloned from the remote repo. I imported a different Joomla installation and created a separate branch for the new code.

I am using one workspace to push to the remote master and the other workspace to push to the remote branch. I can 'see' both branches in both workspaces and I get myself confused because they are not usually in sync. And I get very confused when it comes to merging something from the master into the side branch. So far I have muddled along but I can't help feeling this is wrong and bound to lead to disaster.

It would be fair to say I don't know nearly enough about Eclipse or Git to figure out how I should have set this project up in the first place. And I don't know the exact steps I followed to set up the structure I have right now.

Can someone offer advice on a practical repo and workspace structure for working on branches that require different testing environments?